# Vimeo API v3: Get videos by Album id

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

In v2 we had the api endpoint: vimeo.albums.getVideos where you could specify a particular album id to get its videos.

In v3 I do not see an equivalent, only the https://api.vimeo.com/me/albums/{album_id} which is only for the logged in user.

Am I looking past it, or has the album by id been removed? (I am still collecting info for specs so not yet able to experiment with things like /album/{album_id})

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the code set up to where I can actually try it now, and yes:

```
https://api.vimeo.com/albums/<album_id>/videos
```

works fine, although undocumented. Hopefully that's just an omission & there's no plans to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

`/me` is simply an alias for `/users/{user_id}`.

If you know the users user_id and the album id you can get the videos with `/users/{user_id}/albums/{album_id}/videos`

Comment: ah, that is helpful to know. unfortunately, we will not know the user id, only the album.

it seems strange they would leave such a basic endpoint out

Comment: What is your workflow? I've worked with many users about this issue and have yet to find one that needed to access an album from just the id.

Comment: we are updating a plugin that allows people to make galleries for their site; this used to be one of the options available, so we simply want to upgrade

Comment: So the user was manually entering an album id or something? You should be able to find all albums by a user id (/users/{id}/albums/{id}) and let the user select the albums they want from a list. Additionally if the user is connected to your application, you can probably assume that the album ids are all for that user id.

Comment: I'm not sure that assumption is correct - this backend allows them to post up based on album id alone. I will check with the PM about how he thinks this is being used by most people

Comment: hey - PM says users simply grab the album id from url on Vimeo site & drop it in, and yes they use it a lot. Is there any workaround we can use for the same functionality? Any way we can work with you to get that back in v3?

Comment: I recommend listing the albums on your own website, it should be a much better user experience than copying and pasting. In the meanwhile, try /albums/{id}, it *might* work.